# How to install rabbitmq-perf-test

Tags: rabbitmq

I am new user to use rabbitmq-perf-test, and I seldom use maven.

I git clone the rabbitmq-perf-test from this web site https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-perf-test , but I have no idea about what to do afterwards.

The guide mentions little about installation command.

I try to run :

`[root@test]$ runjava com.rabbitmq.perf.PerfTest`

and get this error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class com.rabbitmq.perf.PerfTest`

anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download the binaries  from https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-perf-test/releases

```
wget https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-perf-test/releases/download/v1.2.0/rabbitmq-perf-test-1.2.0-bin.zip

unzip rabbitmq-perf-test-1.2.0-bin.zip

cd rabbitmq-perf-test-1.2.0/

bin/runjava com.rabbitmq.perf.PerfTest
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :D, I build the binaries from source code. then it also works.